# Minimizing nonnegative weighted sum

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

For this optimization problem:

$$\min_w w^T\delta, \text{such that }\sum_iw_i = q, w_i \ge 0, \delta_i \ge0$$

My intuition says that the minimization of this problem is simply assigning the constrained value $q$ to the minimum $\delta_i$. Formally, I want to prove the following inequality:

$$q\delta_1 \le w_1\delta_1 + w_2\delta_2 \le w_1\delta_1 + w_2\delta_2 + w_3\delta_3 \le \dots \le w_1\delta_1 + w_2\delta_2 + \dots + w_n\delta_n$$

where $\delta_i$'s are ordered in ascending order (i.e., $\delta_1$ is the smallest), and the summation of weights for each term is $q$, so $w_1 + w_2 = q$ in the second term of the inequality.

Is my intuition correct? If so, any leads where to start?

Comment: Your inequalities are incorrect (if I am interpreting them to apply to any assignment that meets the constraints) but not needed to prove the (true) conjecture. To see the inequalities fail just have all $\delta_i$ values the same and consider equal sharing: all w the same.

Comment: To prove the conjecture just prove the (single) inequality $$ w_1\delta_1+...+w_n\delta_n\geq (w_1+...+w_n)\delta_1$$ which holds for any nonnegative $w_i$ values (assuming $\delta_1$ is less than or equal to all other $\delta_i$ values).

Comment: @Michael I understand now that my inequalities are not needed to prove my conjecture. However, and out of curiosity, I think if we add the possibility of equality (see my edit) that would make it correct, do you agree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good intuition.

We have

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=2}^n w_i\delta_i & \ge \sum_{i=2}^n w_i\delta_1 \\
&= \delta _1 \left(\sum_{i=2}^n w_i\right) \\
&= \delta_1 (q-w_1)
\end{align}

Rearrange the inequality and you should be able to reach your conclusion.

Interpretation:

View $\delta_i$ as the unit product price by the $i$-th supplier and we want to purchase $q$ units of products, to minimize the cost, purchase all at the cheapest price.